# Updating an Azure table TableEntity with a DateTimeOffset throws NotImplemented exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have the following code which tries to update the following entity class which happens to contain a DateTimeOffset, This however throws an NotImplementedException. Has anybody else seen this?

```
[System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")]
public sealed class CollectorStateEntity : TableEntity
{
    public CollectorStateEntity()
    {}

    public CollectorStateEntity(string collectorName, string tenantInstance)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = tenantInstance;
        this.RowKey = collectorName;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset StartingTime { get; set; }
}


    public static void UpdateCollectorStateEntityInTableStore(string connectionString, string tableName, string tenantInstance, string collectorName)
    {
        // Get Access to the table
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetTableServiceContext();


        CollectorStateEntity specificEntity =
            (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<CollectorStateEntity>(tableName)
             where e.PartitionKey == tenantInstance && e.RowKey == collectorName
             select e).FirstOrDefault();

        specificEntity.StartingTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("01/27/2014 10:35:00 AM -08:00");

        serviceContext.UpdateObject(specificEntity);
        serviceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries();
    }
```

When trying to do an update when calling UpdateCollectorStateEntityInTableStore I get a StorageException with Message = "NotImplemented". Do I have any other options other than serializing\deserializing DateTimeOffset to string ?

Comment: Is DateTimeOffset supported by Azure?  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj553018.aspx it isn't?

Comment: You are right, however inserts and deletes with an Entity containing DateTimeOffset work fine, looks like the team just hasn't implemented Update. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Brendan, because `DateTimeOffset` is not a supported data type in Azure Table Storage, you're getting this error. A few things you could do are:

1. As you mentioned, you could use a `String` or `DateTime` type property instead of `DateTimeOffset`.
2. Another alternative would be to do the serialization/deserialization yourself. For this you would need to override [`ReadEntity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.readentity.aspx) and [`WriteEntity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.writeentity.aspx) methods.